# move_uploaded_file not uploading image

Tags: php, mysql, image-uploading

I am trying to upload a file to an images folder and also insert the directory path into a `mysql` db.

Here is my `HTML` form

```
<form enctype="multipart/form-data" method="post" action="newfacility.php">
        <fieldset>
            <legend>New Facility</legend>
            ...
            <label for="photo">Facility Photo:</label>                     
            <input type="file" id="facilityphoto" name="facilityphoto" /><br />
            <label for="province">Photo Description:</label>
            <input type="text" id="photodesc" name="photodesc" /><br />
            ....
            <input type="submit" value="Create" name="submit" />
        </fieldset>
    </form>
```

newfacility.php

```
require_once('../appvars.php');
require_once('upload_image.php');

//connect to db and test connection.
$dbc = mysqli_connect(DB_HOST, DB_USER, DB_PASSWORD, DB_NAME);        
if (!$dbc) {
    die("Connection failed: " . mysqli_connect_error());
}

if (isset($_POST['submit'])) {
    // Grab the user data from the POST
    $facilityNumber = mysqli_real_escape_string($dbc, trim($_POST['facilitynumber']));
    ....
    ....

    //This is defined in appvars.php -- define('MM_UPLOADPATH', 'images/');

    //facility photo
    $facilityPhoto = MM_UPLOADPATH . basename($_FILES["facilityphoto"]["name"]);
    $facilityPhotoDesc = mysqli_real_escape_string($dbc, trim($_POST['photodesc']));

    // check if the faciliy info already exists.
    if (!empty($facilityNumber) && !empty($facilityName) && !empty($facilityAddress) && !empty($facilityCity)) {

        $query = "SELECT * FROM facility WHERE facility_number = '$facilityNumber' AND facility_name = '$facilityName' "
                . "AND facility_address = '$facilityAddress' AND facility_city = '$facilityCity'";

        $data = mysqli_query($dbc, $query);
        //if the facility is unique insert the data into the database
        if (mysqli_num_rows($data) == 0) {
            //insert into facility table
            $query = "INSERT INTO facility (facility_id, account_id, facility_number, facility_name, facility_address,"
                    . " facility_city, facility_province, facility_postal_code, facility_photo, facility_roof_plan,"
                    . " facility_roof_size, facility_roof_size_inspected, facility_last_inspected_date, facility_inspected_by)"
                    . " VALUES (NULL, '$selectedAssocAccount', '$facilityNumber', '$facilityName', '$facilityAddress', "
                    . "'$facilityCity', '$facilityProvince', '$facilityPostalCode', '$facilityRoofSize', "
                    . "'$facilityRoofSizeInspected', '$facilityDayInspected', '$facilityInspectedBy')";
            mysqli_query($dbc, $query);

            //query used to get the facility_id of the facility we had just entered -- I haven't tested this yet.
            $getFacilityID = "SELECT facility_id FROM facility WHERE facility_number = '$facilityNumber' AND facility_name = '$facilityName' "
                . "AND facility_address = '$facilityAddress' AND facility_city = '$facilityCity'";

            $facilityID = mysqli_query($dbc, $getFacilityID);

            //insert into photo table
            $photoQuery = "INSERT INTO photo (photo_id, facility_id, photo, photo_desc)"
                        . "VALUES (NULL, $facilityID, $facilityPhoto, $facilityPhotoDesc)";
            mysqli_query($dbc, $photoQuery);

            // Confirm success with the user
            echo '<p>You have succesfully created a new facility. '
                . 'Please go back to the <a href="/admin.php">admin panel</a>.</p>';

            //testing to see if I can view the image
            echo '<img class="profile" src="' . MM_UPLOADPATH . $facilityPhoto . '"/>';

            //close db connection
            mysqli_close($dbc);
            exit();
        }
```

And finally here is upload_image.php

```
if(isset($_FILES["facilityphoto"])) { 
    // Check if file already exists
    if (file_exists($facilityPhoto)) {
        echo "Sorry, facility photo already exists.";
    }
    if($_FILES['facilityphoto']['error'] !==0) { 
        echo "Error uploading facility photo image.";
    } else {
        if (move_uploaded_file($_FILES["facilityphoto"]["tmp_name"], $facilityPhoto)) {
            echo "The file ".( $_FILES["facilityphoto"]["name"]). " has been uploaded.";
        } else {
            echo "Sorry, there was an error uploading the facility photo.";
       }
    }
}
```

So the error I keep hitting right now is: `echo "Sorry, there was an error uploading the facility photo.";`

I don't understand what I am doing wrong here that is resulting in the image not being uploaded into my `images/` directory.

Comment: As far as I can see, you did not even checked if the _upload_ of the file was successful …

Comment: You are confusing the actual _uploading_ part with moving the already uploaded file to a different location from the temp directory … I am talking about this: http://php.net/manual/en/features.file-upload.errors.php

Comment: How is `newfacility.php` being invoked? Is it being included by `upload_image.php`? What is the value of `MM_UPLOADPATH`?

Comment: @CBroe Ohhh hmm, So am I even uploading anything here? How exactly would I check the upload of the file?

Comment: The Errors array in $_FILE

Comment: You need to check if `$_FILES['facilityphoto']['error']` equals `UPLOAD_ERR_OK` resp. `0`. If so, then the file upload itself was o.k., and something goes wrong after that. But you should exclude that as the reason for your script not working first (and handle it appropriately, in case it happens in production.)

Comment: @robbmj `newfacility.php` is invoked when the user clicks a button, and `upload_image.php` is being included in that as seen above. The value of `MM-UPLOADPATH` is explained in a comment.

Comment: If that’s not it, then make sure you have `display_errors` and `error_reporting` set up to report potential issues with moving the file – if the file you’re trying to move is a valid uploaded file, but can’t be moved for some other reason, then PHP will issue a warning.

Comment: I see, I think @mikeO was correct `$facilityPhoto` is not defined when you call the `upload_image.php`

Comment: Did you set the path where the file will be saved

Comment: @robbmj see my comment on his post. However I am not "calling" `upload_image.php` it is just `required_once`. How would I go about defining `$facilityPhoto` and then "calling" `upload_image.php?`

Comment: I did see the comment you left of the answer and I believe that you are mistaken. I would suggest that you rewrite the upload script as a callable function and then call it when you need it.

Comment: @robbmj I replaced the lines as he mentioned in his answer, I am still getting the same result.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am going to provide an answer that addresses only the file upload problem, all the database stuff is striped from the answer as it is not relevant.

```
// returns true only if the file was written to $to, 
// the value of $status_msg will be a user friendly string
// representing the outcome.
function save_facility_photo($from, $to, &$status_msg) {
    // Check if file already exists
    if (file_exists($to)) {
        $status_msg = "Sorry, facility photo already exists.";
        return false;
    } 
    if (move_uploaded_file($from, $to)) {
        $status_msg = "The file ".basename($to)." has been uploaded.";
        return true;
    }
    $status_msg = "Sorry, there was an error uploading the facility photo.";
    return false;
}

if (isset($_POST['submit'])) {
    define('MM_UPLOADPATH', 'images/');

    $facilityPhoto = MM_UPLOADPATH . basename($_FILES["facilityphoto"]["name"]);

    if ($_FILES['facilityphoto']['error'] == UPLOAD_ERR_OK) {
        $status_msg = '';
        $from = $_FILES["facilityphoto"]["tmp_name"];
        $saved = save_facility_photo($from, $facilityPhoto, $status_msg);
    }
    else {
        // handle upload error
    }
    // continue with code
}
```

The following is an explanation of what I think is happening in your scripts.

At the top of `newfacility.php`, `require_once('upload_image.php');` is called. Now lets step though `upload_image.php` **noting that `$facilityPhoto` has not yet been defined**

```
// this is very likely true
if(isset($_FILES["facilityphoto"])) { 
    // $facilityPhoto is undefined so file_exists(NULL) will return false
    if (file_exists($facilityPhoto)) { }
    // the image upload was probably successful, so we jump to the else branch
    if($_FILES['facilityphoto']['error'] !==0) { 

    } 
    else {
        // $facilityPhoto is undefined move_uploaded_file('p/a/t/h', NULL) 
        // will return false, so we jump to the else branch
        if (move_uploaded_file($_FILES["facilityphoto"]["tmp_name"], $facilityPhoto)) {

        } 
        else {
            // resulting in this error
            echo "Sorry, there was an error uploading the facility photo.";
       }
    }
}
```

Comment: I got this to work once with the actual uploading of my images to my folder, and for some reason cannot reproduce the result I need a second time..(I am using different pictures)

Answer (score 1):

Replace these lines:

```
if (move_uploaded_file($_FILES["facilityphoto"]["tmp_name"], $facilityPhoto)){
   echo "The file ".( $_FILES["facilityphoto"]["name"]). " has been uploaded.";
}
```

with these:

```
if (move_uploaded_file($_FILES["facilityphoto"]["tmp_name"], 'images/'. $_FILES["facilityphoto"]["name"])){
   echo "The file ".( $_FILES["facilityphoto"]["name"]). " has been uploaded.";
}
```

Comment: The value of `$facilityPhoto` is  "images/imagename.jpeg". So I am not understanding why I would replace my variable with the hardcoded directory. Just because, I tested this and it is still resulting the same (as expected).

Comment: I'm not sure if this answers the OP's question.   It just checks in the code to see if it has not uploaded, but not to ensure that it IS uploaded